# C# network scanner unable to detect other devices, think due to firewalls

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am currently creating a C# network scanner, but I have run into an issue where I am not able to detect devices other than the one running the code. I have been following a couple guides as to how to go about it, but even if I just copy and paste their code it runs into the same issue. I have a feeling it might be due to firewalls because of this but if that is the case how would I do that?

This is my boiled down code using just console. It runs through all the IPs, while rather slow, and picks up this device but not the others I have connected. It uses the prebuilt ping class and sends it to every possible device on the subnet.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ping myPing;
            PingReply reply;
            IPAddress address;
            IPHostEntry host;

            string iP = "172.20.10.";
            Console.WriteLine("start loop");
            for (int i = 2; i < 240; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                string deviceIP = iP + i.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("selected " + deviceIP);
                myPing = new Ping();
                reply = myPing.Send(deviceIP);
                Console.WriteLine("contacting " + deviceIP);

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(deviceIP);
                    Console.WriteLine(host.HostName.ToString() + " is connected");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("^non existant^");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end loop");
        }
```

Comment: A device itself doesn't talk, a program talks. So instead of just pinging an IP address, you also need to add a port number, on which a program is listening.

Comment: @rotgers Please read this on ICMP pings: https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/e-series-santricity/sm-hardware/what-are-icmp-ping-responses.html

Comment: @I8platypus Welcome to SO. Read the link I posted. It's possible ping replies are disabled via policy. It could be a firewall blocking it too.

Comment: What I usually do is to send all the Pings without waiting for results.  Then read the ARP table which will contain the responses.  You can look at ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP -A.  Or you can use Ping Async so you do not have to do one at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This will help me greatly.